# ms access 2007 - forms

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I would like to apologize for my ignorance beforehand. I've studied some tutorials about ms access and i'm still quite lost. I am not sure how to phrase this question because I am not familiar with access terms and such.

I am trying to create a form with these problems

1. filling up a text box would allow me to select in a dropdown field related fields from the table.
   e.g. putting uni in the textbox would show unicorn, unicode, university in the drop down
2. button that allows me to add more rows in this form.
   e.g. clicking [add more rows] would generate a row of textboxes that are fillable
3. button that allows me to submit the whole form into the database (this would have to account for the growing number of rows based on the [add more rows])
4. a reset form button (i've read that some people just open and close the form in a button)

I have some knowledge of SQL but I am totally new to access. I would greatly appreciate links or some guide as to where I would be able to find these answers as I am quite confused as to what to google myself.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, this is way too broad. Focus on one problem at a time. Research it, try things. When you have a *specific* problem, ask here. Stack Overflow isn't for finding tutorials, see [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: Should I separate my four problems into four questions is that what you mean? because I thought each question was quite specific. Thanks

Comment: 1. Search for **search as you type**. 2. + 3. need nothing special, that's inbuilt in **bound forms**. 4. hit Escape or call `Form.Undo`.